# Template class for non-inline member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to follow an example here:

http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

But I dont want to inline my function definitions with my class definition.

Will I have to put

```
template<typename Data>
concurrent_queue<Data>::
```

in front of all my function defs and constructors?

Comment: I have *tried* exactly what I just posted, but it is quite ugly.

Comment: So, is there a problem? What's the question? C++ isn't a beauty contest.

Comment: The question is how to have a templated class without having to inline the definition of everything.

Comment: You mean "how to define a templated class without writing all the method definitions inside the class definition" -- yes, exactly like that: you just add the template parameter to every method signature. No way around it, after all you have to be able to refer to the parameter in the body! And as DeadMG says, you still have to make the entire thing visible to the client. You cannot "compile" templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will, and the definitions will still need to be in the header file. This is why everyone uses inline definitions- because they basically have to be inline anyway.

Comment: They don't _have_ to stay in the header file, but the use-cases of explicit instantiation are admittedly rather limited. Btw, I often avoid class-inline definitions for sake of less noisy self-documentation, and put the definition into some "foo.inl.h" (or so) header.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is no way around that syntax (except with token-producing symbol-destroying evil evil `#define` macros).

Personally, I either inline them in the class template declaration/definition, or for the sake of better self-documentation put the definitions into some "inl"-file, like so:

*foo.h*

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

namespace bar {

    template <typename T>
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo () ;
        virtual ~Foo();
    };

}

#include "foo.inl.h"
#endif // FOO_H
```

*foo.inl.h*

```
#ifndef FOO_INL_H
#define FOO_INL_H

namespace bar {

template <typename T>
inline Foo<T>::Foo () {
}

template <typename T>
inline Foo<T>::~Foo () {
}

}
#endif // FOO_INL_H
```

Note that I explicitly declare them `inline` then. This improves consistency of the style, and if you happen to specialize the template, you have to do it anyways:

```
template <>
inline Foo<int>::Foo() {
}
```

Without the `inline`, you suffer the same pain like when forgetting it on ordinary functions defined in header files (read: multiple definition errors).

Answer (score 0):

The functions do not need to be inline, but it's better if they are inside the header file:

```
/* in .h file */
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
   void f();
}

/* this also in .h file */
template<class T>
void A<T>::f()
{
}
```

This is often necessary to split the class and the functions to separate parts, but both of them needs to be in the header file for templates to work.